# How to use selenium webdriver to randomly click on a button and insert numbers to the input box displayed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a dynamic page where IDs, Xpath and name attributes changes from time to time.
In order to make my scripts stable. I want to randomly click on 5 buttons on the page and then send a random amount between 1-100 to the input box available and then finally click the Submit button(SCOMMETTI) to place a bet. The link to the page is below:
http://sports.williamhill.it/bet_ita/it/betting/y/5/Calcio.html

The script below is failing because the events keep changing at the backend:

```
enter code here
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tup_selection570167price']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='slip_sgl_stake570167L']")).sendKeys("5");
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tup_selection570176price']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='slip_sgl_stake570176L']")).sendKeys("10");
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tup_selection570179price']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='slip_sgl_stake570179L']")).sendKeys("4");
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tup_selection570191price']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='slip_sgl_stake570191L']")).sendKeys("7");
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tup_selection570200price']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='slip_sgl_stake570200L']")).sendKeys("100");
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    System.out.println("Placing amount on Bet");
```

Comment: I have tried using the below:

Comment: update your post above.

Comment: Thanks Paul, the script above keep failing becos the events are updated at backend, this is the reason, I want to randomly click the events buttons that appears on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If your IDs, Xpath and name attributes changes from time to time, you should store in an array and with a loop you can click on them. like this

```
 ArrayList<WebElement> input_type = (ArrayList<WebElement>)   
 driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
            for (int i = 0; i < input_type.size(); i++) {
                 for(WebElement type : input_type)
                   {

                   if(type.getAttribute("type").equals("button")){
                     type.click();
                     type.submit();
            }
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on anwser above. Thanks

Comment: if you will write this code in your function, So this function would store all input tag like [ <input name="j_username" id="UID" type="text" placeholder="Username"> ] Now it will store all available  input tag in array then by loop we can perform several operation on particular element like click , sendkey etc. 
I hope you got the point.